# Behavior for receive(on:) for DispatchQueue.main

Tags: swift, combine

Given the code below from a class:

```
cancellable = input
    .receive(on: scheduler)
    .map { ... }
    .sink(receiveValue: { value in
        self.state = value
    })
```

where `input` is a PassthroughSubject.

Now, when `scheduler` is the main queue or the RunLoop.main AND input will be called from the main thread, does `receive(on: scheduler)` programmatically optimise away an explicit dispatch to the main queue?

So, basically something like this:

```
 if Thread.isMainThread { 
    /* execute closure */
 } else { 
    /* dispatch closure async to main */
 }
```

The documentation for `receive(on:)` gives a vague hint, that it might perform some optimisations:

"Prefer receive(on:options:) over explicit use of dispatch queues"

```
pub.sink {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        // Do something.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No, `receive(on:)` does not optimize away the dispatch. Doing so could lead to a deadlock. Example:

```swift
let l = Lock()

let cancellable = input
    .receive(on: scheduler)
    .map { ... }
    .sink(receiveValue: { value in
        l.lock()
        self.state = value
        l.unlock()
    })

l.lock()
input.send(1)
l.unlock()
```

If the dispatch were eliminated, this example would try to lock the already-locked lock `l`, and hang (or crash if it can detect the deadlock).

Comment: Ah, I see - even though, I understand that the example using a lock is for illustration only.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the sources for [RunLoop](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/b5570a1aa923d18f5b7a28b06ea2a7424ba65e3b/stdlib/public/Darwin/Foundation/Schedulers%2BRunLoop.swift#L147) and [DispatchQueue](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/2eb460de4d675a0947215bc1878bb61f1a3dcd49/stdlib/public/Darwin/Dispatch/Schedulers%2BDispatchQueue.swift#L243), it doesn't look like there is such an optimisation in their conformance to the `Scheduler` protocol.

But to be fair, there might be lower level optimisations at play.

Comment: Regarding RunLoop, I don't think, it can be implemented with arbitrary threads, only with the "well known" main thread. DispatchQueue has no mechanism for returning the current queue (except in dispatch precondition). So, I think, if any code makes the optimisation, it must be in `receive(on:)` or the Combine Scheduler. ;)